# Calling Java Methods from Visual C/C++ using C++/CLI 

Tags: java, c++-cli, java-native-interface

I'm getting a "error LNK1104: cannot open file {path}\jvm.lib" when trying tocompile a VS C++/CLI (managed) project. It's very simple and my goal is to call some Java methods in pre-existing java libs - here is the code I'm using:

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <jni_md.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "JBridge.h"

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace JBridge 
{

public ref class JniBridge
{
    // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.


public:
    void HelloWorldTest()
    {
        System::Console::WriteLine("Hello Worldl from managed C++!");
    }

    JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM ** jvm) 
    {
        JNIEnv *env;
        JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

        JavaVMOption options; 
        //Path to the java source code     
        options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=D:\\Java Src\\TestStruct"; 
        vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6; //JDK version. This indicates version 1.6
        vm_args.nOptions = 1;
        vm_args.options = &options;
        vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

        int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
        if(ret < 0)
            printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM\n");       
        return env;
    }
    };
}
```

I've verified the file does exist in the path location and I've added it to the project properties for the include dir and the linker property pages.

**Update**
Got the jvm.lib to be linked with a bit more fiddling.

Compilation causes following errors during build:

Error   1   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000A) "extern "C" long __stdcall JNI_CreateJavaVM(struct JavaVM_ * *,void * *,void *)" (?JNI_CreateJavaVM@@$$J212YGJPAPAUJavaVM_@@PAPAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "struct JNIEnv_ * __cdecl create_vm(struct JavaVM_ * *)" (?create_vm@@$$FYAPAUJNIEnv_@@PAPAUJavaVM_@@@Z)  c:\Temp\CLRTest\JBridge\JBridge\JBridge.obj JBridge
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" long __stdcall JNI_CreateJavaVM(struct JavaVM_ * *,void * *,void *)" (?JNI_CreateJavaVM@@$$J212YGJPAPAUJavaVM_@@PAPAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "struct JNIEnv_ * __cdecl create_vm(struct JavaVM_ * *)" (?create_vm@@$$FYAPAUJNIEnv_@@PAPAUJavaVM_@@@Z)   c:\Temp\CLRTest\JBridge\JBridge\JBridge.obj JBridge
Error   3   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   c:\temp\CLRTest\JBridge\Debug\JBridge.dll   JBridge

Comment: BTW - i'm trying to run this in x64 which is what the JVM is...

Comment: Looks like it can't find the jvm. Did you set JAVA_HOME, if using env variable? Did you move the jvm from its original location?

Comment: @Jason didn't move the location, but I rebooted and it somehow went away. Very odd. Still receiving errors however.

Comment: Did you check to make sure the headers included match the same version of jvm.lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work around was to dynamically load the JVM by using LoadLibrary("path/to/jvm"); and then invoking the native functions.

Comment: I'm struggling with the exact same issue - please add a link to a small working sample app or a link to a blog entry where things are more fleshed out. (Or email me personally)