# Build error when compiling java methods in C++ using jni.h

Tags: java, c++, compilation

I'm trying to run a few methods from Java class in Visual Studio C++ Environment. I got an error related CreateJavaVM.

Would you please help me to find the solution?

I did the following steps.

**Step 1:** JDK 1.6 is installed under the following path: C:\Program Files\Java
The following 2 sub directories are there: jdk1.6.0_45, jre6

**Step 2:** Write a simple java program.

```
public class Sample2
{
   public static int intMethod(int n)
   {
     return n*n;
   }
   public static boolean booleanMethod(boolean bool) 
   {
    return !bool;
    }
 }
```

**Step 3:** Compile the java code:

```
   javac Sample2.java
```

**Step 4:** Create a Visual Studio C++ program. Visual C++ CLR Console Application.

**Step 5:** Add the additional dependencies. (jvm.lib and jvm.dll)
a) Choose the project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies: jvm.lib
b) Choose the project -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Delay Loaded Dlls: jvm.dll

**Step 6:** Add the include directories
a) Choose project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\lib;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\include\win32;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\include

**Step 7:** Write the C++ code to run the java methods.

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include "jni.h"
  #include <jni_md.h>
  using namespace System;

  int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
  {

    JavaVM *jvm;   /* denotes a Java VM */
    JNIEnv *env;  /* pointer to native method interface */
    jint square;
    jboolean not;

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */

    JavaVMOption *options = new JavaVMOption[1];

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\JavaCode";  

   vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
   vm_args.options = options;
   vm_args.nOptions = 1;
   vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

   int res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);

   jclass cls = env->FindClass("Sample2");

   jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "staticInt", "(I)I");

   env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid,10);

   if(cls !=0)
   {   
     mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls,"intMethod","(I)I");    

   if(mid !=0)
   {  
    square = env->CallStaticIntMethod(cls, mid, 5);       
    printf("Result of intMethod: %d\n", square);
   }

   mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "booleanMethod", "(Z)Z");

    if(mid !=0)
    { 
     not = env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(cls, mid, 1);
     printf("Result of booleanMethod: %d\n", not);
    }
 }

 jvm->DestroyJavaVM();

 Console::Read();
 return 0;
}
```

**Step 8:** When I build the project I got the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: 1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------

1>LINK : warning LNK4199: /DELAYLOAD:jvm.dll ignored; no imports found from jvm.dll

1>1.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100000F) for '_jmethodID'; image may not run

1>1.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000016) "extern "C" long __stdcall JNI_CreateJavaVM(struct JavaVM_ * *,void * *,void *)" (?JNI_CreateJavaVM@@$$J212YGJPAPAUJavaVM_@@PAPAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)

1>1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" long __stdcall JNI_CreateJavaVM(struct JavaVM_ * *,void * *,void *)" (?JNI_CreateJavaVM@@$$J212YGJPAPAUJavaVM_@@PAPAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)

1>C:\Users\tveluppillai\Desktop\Test1\1\Debug\1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Would anyone help me to solve this error please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved the error. The following is the working C++ code.

```
// 1.cpp : main project file.

  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include "jni.h"
  #include <windows.h>
  using namespace System;


  int CallJava()
  {

   JavaVM *jvm;   /* denotes a Java VM */

   JNIEnv *env;  /* pointer to native method interface */

   jint square;

   jboolean not;

   JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */

   JavaVMOption *options = new JavaVMOption[1];

   options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\JavaCode";  

   vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
   vm_args.options = options;
   vm_args.nOptions = 1;
   vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

   HINSTANCE hinstLib;  

    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_45\\jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll"));

  if(hinstLib==0)
  {
   printf("Error");
  }

  if(hinstLib!= NULL)
  {
  typedef jint (JNICALL *PtrCreateJavaVM)(JavaVM **, void **, void *);

    PtrCreateJavaVM ptrCreateJavaVM =  (PtrCreateJavaVM)GetProcAddress(hinstLib,"JNI_CreateJavaVM");

   int res = ptrCreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

   jclass cls = env->FindClass("Sample2");

   jmethodID mid;   

   if(cls !=0)
   {   
    mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls,"intMethod","(I)I");
    if(mid !=0)
    {  
      square = env->CallStaticIntMethod(cls, mid, 5);       
      printf("Result of intMethod: %d\n", square);
    }

   mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "booleanMethod", "(Z)Z");
   if(mid !=0)
   { 
     not = env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(cls, mid, 1);
     printf("Result of booleanMethod: %d\n", not);
    }
  }
   jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
 }
else
{
  printf("Library is NULL");
}
   Console::Read();
   return 0;
}

 int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
 {
 CallJava();
 Console::Read();
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`JNI_CreateJavaVM` is defined in `jni.h`, so my guess is that your linker is not finding `jni.h`. I actually put that file and `jni_md.h` in my project directory with my source code.

Note that `jni.h` includes `jni_md.h`, so having `#include <jni_md.h>` in your source code is redundant.

Comment: I added the header in the C++ solution folder. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Well, the error is a linker error, so it is not finding it. We are not mind readers. Without going through all the settings in your project personally I have no idea of where you screwed up. If you added jvm.lib as a dependency, then the linker SHOULD be finding it. If you can try posting the actual compile and link text commands.

Comment: It certainly is a link error. Since I'm using visual studio IDE, I didn't have to write any commands to compile and link. This is what I did. Step 1: Right click on the project and choose the properties and go to Linker -> Input and type jvm.lib in the Additional Dependencies and typed jvm.dll in Dealyed Loaded Dlls Step 2: Go to general under Linker and give the path to jvm.lib and jvm.dll in the Additional Library Directories. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

Comment: @TevaganthanVeluppillai Visual Studio actually uses a command line. The GUI just hides it from you. There is also a build log. In the output window it should tell you where the build log is.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I found a way to get build log from the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx Since my build log is a text file and I don't see a way to attach text file here. So, I have my build log is here.https://www.dropbox.com/s/wrsoolkc52qmf51/OutputLog.txt?dl=0 When you have time please have a look and let me know if I miss anything.

Comment: I think my error is similar to the following error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999913/calling-java-methods-from-visual-c-c-using-c-cli  I may need to dynamically load the jvm.dll

Comment: I just checked it again and  the following link works fine and it just shows a text file. [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/wrsoolkc52qmf51/OutputLog.txt?dl=0) Now, I solved the linker issue though. But, I'm still getting error in jvm creation part. I can't post the code in the comment section. I will share the code via the following link. [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/26lyclldv1mfglc/Code.txt?dl=0)